# Has anybody been able to install PyWeka?

Tags: python, windows, setuptools, distribute

I need to install in python 2.6 or 2.7 for windows the library PyWeka0.3dev, It says it requires setuptools, which I installed but then they told me it was a deprecated instalation library and I installed distribute, then I downloaded the PyWeka compressed package and each time I try to install it neither with setup.py nor with easy_install (where it says something like no module ez_setup). Can anybody give me a clue about how to do this?

Comment: Can you explain to me why you are trying to hard to install this module, even though it's clear that it's authors don't really know what they are doing? I think you are just gonna have endless problems.

Comment: just a thought: since you want weka in Python and weka was written in Java, have you given a look at Jython?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned to you via Aardvark (yes, I am omnipresent), the module in question is broken. You can't easy_install it. It's a bug in PyWeka.

You can download the file from PyPI, http://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyWeka/0.3dev, and unpack it.

In the file setup.py, remove the following two lines:

```
from ez_setup import use_setuptools
use_setuptools()
```

And install it by running

```
python setup.py install
```

You need to have installed numpy and NamedMatrix (which has the same bug as PyWeka) first.

However, you mentioned you are on Windows. I strongly doubt that PyWeka will work on Windows. There are some Unix specific code in it.

And I still really want to know why the authors are reading files by calling `cat` from `subprocess`. That seems pretty pointless and is  together with the broken install, good enough reason for me to keep *far* away from that module. I suspect it's authors simply have no idea what they are doing.

That, or they are geniuses.

Comment: Calling `cat` from `subprocess` would be a natural Python implementation of the often-seen shell silliness of doing `cat foo_file | some_command` instead of `some_command <foo_file` or `some_command foo_file`

Comment: @John Machin: Right. But the code doesn't even pipe it anywhere. It really, honestly, reads the contents of a file, by running `cat` in subprocess.Popen().

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time, but let me tell you that I removed also other lines related to setuptools and it seemed like it was about to compile, but then installing namedmatrix was kind of impossible cause it includes things in c related to setuptools.

Comment: @mariana soffer: Right, namedmatrix has a c module, yes, so you also need a c-compiler installed.

Answer (score 0):

A punk/goth approach to programming probably has the right to be..

To get the C-compliation part to work on windows you either need (1) to have Visual Studio of the same version that was used to compile the python version you are using, or (2) mingw which is a bit trickier to set up.

Comment: I did set up mingw but have not been able to use it, maybe cause the trickiness you are refering to. So visual studio, ok I will have it in mind, right now I can not install it but I will try on the future. Let me know if you have any trick about mingw for installing namedmatrix with an example